# Assign variable value to hidden field

Tags: javascript, html

I am binding a query into the javascript element. like below

```
StrPriFnName = "FunGetAddInfo1(" + document.getElementById('CmbDocumentType').value + ")";
        var ObjPriXMLHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        ObjPriXMLHTTP.open("GET", "FrmInwardXMLHTTP.aspx?para=" + StrPriFnName, false);
        ObjPriXMLHTTP.send("");
        var StrStatusXMLHTTP = ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText;
        if (ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText != "") {
            StrPriRow = ObjPriXMLHTTP.responseText.split('|');
            for (IntPriI = 0; IntPriI < StrPriRow.length - 1; IntPriI++) {
                StrPriCol = StrPriRow[IntPriI].split('~');
                var ObjPriOption = document.createElement("hidden");
                ObjPriOption.text = StrPriCol[1];
                ObjPriOption.value = StrPriCol[0];
                document.getElementById('HidEmailId').value = ObjPriOption.value;
            }
        }
    }
```

but, I am not getting value in `HidEmailId`

as my `ObjPriOption.value` contains value.

How to assign the value in the hidden field

Comment: Show html of hidden element

Comment: @Leopard: It is `<input type="hidden" id="HidEmailId" runat="server" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
document.getElementById('<%= HidEmailId.ClientID %>').value;
```

You are using asp.net hidden field whichs `ID` is changed according to `contentplaceholder id`